# Xamarin code generation designer is breaking app

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, designer

In my application, when I edit a .xib file and run the application it triggers some tool to go through all my .designer.cs files and injects code. This is breaking my application and I want to turn it off.

My controllers inherit from a basecontroller that has it's on IB Outlet fields. The code generated finds those IB Outlets and puts them in the subclass' designer file. This hides the base controller's implementation.

Also, I'm sure what I'm doing is bad design and I re-architect the UI but not now.

How do I turn off this code generation? I went through the Xamarin settings but I didn't see anything.

Answer (score 1):

The generation of the `.designer.cs` files is an integral part of the Xamarin iOS Designer and cannot be disabled.

Those files should *never* be modified by you as they will be automatically regenerated.